# PHP script to search a webpage for specific word

Tags: php

I am trying to build a script that searches a webpage for a specific word. Whenever I run the script it returns that the word exists, even if it doesn't.

This is the script:

```
<?php
$db->query("select id from ".prefix." book where book='$book'");
$id=$db->f("id");

$text = file_get_contents('http://www.somesite.com/item?keywords=$id');
echo (stristr ($text, 'Eminescu')) ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
?>
```

Comment: Could you add your script to the question, please?

Comment: We can't help unless you show us your script.  What are we supposed to tell you without seeing your code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Maybe the webpage really does contain 'word'?

Comment: It seems is working now, but if i want to search a url more complex and add a variable from a database to that url how it should look?

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Please show us what you mean by including an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Just did, check it now, thanks!

Comment: According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/function.stristr.php), you should explicitly test the result of `stristr` for boolean `FALSE`: `echo (FALSE === stristr($text,'eminescu')) ? 'Online' : 'Offline';`

Comment: echo (stristr ($text, 'Eminescu')) ? 'Online' : 'Offline'; .......Shouldn't 'Eminescu' be $id?

Comment: @rakeshjain No Eminescu is the specific word i am searching the webpage for and $id is just a page id on the website.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing why you're using `stristr`, I'm going to say just use `strpos` instead (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.somesite.com/item?keywords=$id');
$intext = strpos($text, 'Eminescu') !== false; // note !==, not !=
echo $intext ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
```

but is rather silly, because you're just doing substring searching. If the html contains "LollerphanEminescutiomatic", then this code (as well as the code you tried to write) will say "yeah, it's in there". And it'll be right, but it might be useless as a result.